# Protractor Test Cases Not Working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

Protractor Test Cases Not Working in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 Enterprise

```
Protractor.conf.js has below configuration.

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe'],

multiCapabilities: [
  {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'version': '11'
  }
]
```

When I try to run either ng e2e command to run the test cases, I get

> Driver.version: unknown exception like below.

```
**Exception Trace:** 

[11:37:33] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.42.exe up to date
[11:37:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:37:33] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[11:37:37] E/launcher - Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "count": 1,
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "version": "11",
    "platform": "ANY"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "internet explorer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'DN13961', ip: '10.12.56.135', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[11:37:37] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "count": 1,
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "version": "11",
    "platform": "ANY"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "internet explorer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'DN13961', ip: '10.12.56.135', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:635:14)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\atptszk\Documents\bcui1001\bcui-trial01\bcui\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[11:37:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Couple of trials I did as below.

1. I have tried manually downloading the IEDriverServer.exe and started it manually before running ng e2e.
2. Downloaded the IEDriverServer.exe and copied under selenium dir `\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium` and then ran `webdriver-manager update` and `webdriver-manager start` and then `ng e2e` but I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor with IE on Windows 10 fails - error code 199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993206/protractor-with-ie-on-windows-10-fails-error-code-199)

Comment: Here is what solved my problem as per suggestion provided on the link. I have opened 'Registry Editor', did go to below path. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\                                                                 And then created a new feature there by right clicking -> FEATURE_BECACHE -> then right click this feature and then create New->DWORD (32-Bit Value) and then rename the created DWORD as -> 'iexplore.exe'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. package.json will have script like below. (You have to add it under scripts tag).
   "webdriver-nodemodules-update-all-drivers": "cd .\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin & webdriver-manager update --standalone & webdriver-manager update --versions.gecko=v0.22.0 & webdriver-manager update --ie"
2. Make sure protractor.conf.js has localSeleniumStandaloneOpts & multiCapabilities [Code Image. Do like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCF6.png) image code snipped (Unformatted) is below (Copy below code and format it in your ide- pls refer code image here and configure like that.) protractor.conf and format code.

   //directConnect: true,
       localSeleniumStandaloneOpts : {
           //jvmArgs : ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver="] // e.g: "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_X.XX.X.exe"
           jvmArgs : ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules//protractor//node_modules//webdriver-manager//selenium//IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe"] // e.g: "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer_x64_X.XX.X.exe"
           },
         'autoStartStopServer': true,
         multiCapabilities:[
           {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
   //           args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920,1080']
            },
            acceptInsecureCerts: true,
            shardTestFiles: true
          },
          {
           'browserName': 'firefox',
           'marionette': true,
           firefoxOptions: {
     //        args: ['--headless']
           },
           'moz:firefoxOptions': {
             args: [ '--headless' ]
           },
           directConnect: false,
           },
           {
             'browserName': 'internet explorer',
             'platform': 'ANY',
             'version': '11'
           }
        ],
3. Then do run 3 commands - 'npm install', 'npm run webdriver-nodemodules-update-all-drivers' and then 'ng e2e' to run the test cases on (chrome/firefox/internet explorer) browsers. Note that webdriver-nodemodules-update-all-drivers command will only run if you have followed step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what solved my problem as per suggestion provided on the link. I have opened 'Registry Editor', did go to below path.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\`

And then created a new feature there by right clicking -> `FEATURE_BECACHE` -> then right click this feature and then create New->`DWORD (32-Bit Value)` and then rename the created `DWORD` as -> `'iexplore.exe'`

Check the link below for the Registry Setting Being Made.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4AzG.png)

Comment: package.json will have script like